# Where exactly is the Bhagavad Geeta quote that the "ultimate aim of life is to attain moksha" found?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

I regularly watch the Bhagavad Geeta on CD, there, Lord Krishna says that the ultimate goal of human life is to attain Moksha, but man is trapped in temptations, attachment, greed and that's why he keeps taking rebirth.

I want to know the exact reference in Bhagavad Geeta where Lord Krishna says that the purpose of human birth is to attain moksha.

Can someone please let me know the exact chapter number, verse number where Lord Krishna says so?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. You may want to take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. :)

Comment: I don't think there's any explicit mention of any such verse exact-verbatim in the BG.

Comment: @Vivikta a combination of verses will do as well, please mention the references of any mention of it implicitly, it'll be a great help!

Comment: Gita 2.59 to 72.

Comment: Gita 2.59 to 72.   the embodied (dehinaḥ) giving up the taste for sense enjoyment, and by experiencing (dṛṣṭvā) far superior things(param)......  at the end of life (anta-kāle) one attains(ṛcchati)  the spiritual kingdom of God(brahma-nirvāṇam)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There's no exact-verbatim verse in the Śrīmad-Bhagavad-Gītā that says "the Ultimate aim of Life is to attain Mokṣa".

However, indirectly, Mokṣa as "the Ultimate Aim" is implied throughout the Gītā.

Here, I have tried to compile all the verses in my knowledge that talks about Mokṣa or Nirvāṇa, either directly or indirectly:

#### 1. [BG. 2.72](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=72&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1)

> एषा ब्राह्मी स्थितिःपार्थ नैनां प्राप्य विमुह्यति ।
> स्थित्वास्यामन्तकालेऽपि **ब्रह्मनिर्वाण**मृच्छति ॥ ७२ ॥
>
> > 2.72. This is the Brahmic seat (eternal state), O son of Pritha. Attaining to this, none is deluded. Being established therein, even at
> > the end of life, one attains to oneness with Brahman.

#### 2. [BG. 4.16](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=16&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)

> BG. 4.16
>  किं कर्म किमकर्मेति कवयोऽप्यत्र मोहिताः । तत्ते कर्म
> प्रवक्ष्यामि यज्ज्ञात्वा **मोक्ष्यसे**ऽश‍ुभात् ॥ १६ ॥
>
> > 4.16 What is action? What is inaction? As to this, even the wise are confused. Therefore I shall teach thee such action (the nature of
> > action and inaction) by knowing which **thou shalt be liberated** from the
> > evil (of Samsara, the wheel of birth and death).

#### 3. BG. 5.24-25-26

> [BG. 5.24](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=24&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)
>  योऽन्त:सुखोऽन्तरारामस्तथान्तर्ज्योतिरेव य: । स योगी
> **ब्रह्मनिर्वाणं** ब्रह्मभूतोऽधिगच्छति ॥ २४ ॥
>
> > 5.24. He who is happy within, who rejoices within, and who is illuminated within, that Yogi **attains absolute freedom or Moksha**,
> > himself becoming Brahman.
>
> ---
>
> [BG. 5.25](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=25) 
> लभन्ते **ब्रह्मनिर्वाण**मृषय: क्षीणकल्मषा: । छिन्नद्वैधा
> यतात्मान: सर्वभूतहिते रता: ॥ २५ ॥
>
> > 5.25. The sages (Rishis) obtain **absolute freedom or Moksha** they whose sins have been destroyed, whose dualities (perception of dualities or
> > experience of the pairs of opposites) are torn asunder, who are
> > self-controlled, and intent on the welfare of all beings.
>
> ---
>
> [BG. 5.26](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=26) 
> कामक्रोधविमुक्तानां यतीनां यतचेतसाम् । अभितो **ब्रह्मनिर्वाणं**
> वर्तते विदितात्मनाम् ॥ २६ ॥
>
> > 5.26. To the monks who have control over their internal organ, who are free from desire and anger, who have known the Self, there is
> > absorption in Brahman either way.

#### 4. [BG. 5.28](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=28&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)

> यतेन्द्रियमनोबुद्धिर्मुनि**र्मोक्षपरायणः**। विगतेच्छाभयक्रोधो यः सदा मुक्त
> एव सः ॥ २८ ॥
>
> > 5.28. With the senses, the mind, and the intellect (ever) controlled, **having liberation as his supreme goal**, free from desire, fear and
> > anger the sage is verily liberated forever.

#### 5. BG. 6.14-15

> [BG. 6.14](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=6&field_nsutra_value=14)
>  प्रशान्तात्मा विगतभीर्ब्रह्मचारिव्रते स्थित: । मन:
> संयम्य मच्च‍ित्तो युक्त आसीत **मत्पर:** ॥ १४ ॥
>
> > 6.14. Being calm-minded, fearless, firm in the vow of celibacy; controlling mind fully; let the master of Yoga remain, fixing his mind
> > in Me and **having Me [alone] as his supreme goal.**
>
> ---
>
> [BG. 6.15](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=6&field_nsutra_value=15&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)
>  युञ्जन्नेवं सदात्मानं योगी नियतमानस: । शान्तिं
> **निर्वाणपरमां** मत्संस्थामधिगच्छति ॥ १५ ॥
>
> > 6.15 Thus always keeping the mind balanced, the Yogi, with the mind controlled, attains to the peace abiding in Me, which **culminates in
> > liberation**.

#### 6. BG. 9.1 & 9.28

> [BG. 9.1](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=9&field_nsutra_value=1&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)
>  इदं तु ते गुह्यतमं प्रवक्ष्याम्यनसूयवे । ज्ञानं
> विज्ञानसहितं यज्ज्ञात्वा **मोक्ष्यसे**ऽश‍ुभात् ॥ १ ॥
>
> > 9.1 The Blessed Lord said I shall now declare to thee who does not cavil, the greatest secret, the knowledge combined with experience
> > (Self-realisation). Having known this thou shalt be free evil.
>
> ---
>
> [BG. 9.28](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=9&field_nsutra_value=28&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)
>  श‍ुभाश‍ुभफलैरेवं **मोक्ष्यसे** कर्मबन्धनै: ।
> सन्न्यासयोगयुक्तात्मा विमुक्तो मामुपैष्यसि ॥ २८ ॥
>
> > 9.28 Thus shalt thou be freed from the bonds of actions yielding good and evil fruits; with the mind steadfast in the Yoga of renunciation,
> > and **liberated, thou shalt come unto Me**.

#### 7. [BG. 17.25](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=17&field_nsutra_value=25&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)

> तदित्यनभिसन्धाय फलं यज्ञतप:क्रिया: । दानक्रियाश्च विविधा: क्रियन्ते
> **मोक्षकाङ्‌‍क्षिभि:** ॥ २५ ॥
>
> > 17.25 Uttering Tat, without aiming at the fruits, are the acts of sacrifice and austerity and the various acts of gift performed by
> > **the seekers of liberation**.

#### 8. BG. 18.30 & 18.66

> [BG. 18.30](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=30&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)
>  प्रवृत्तिं च निवृत्तिं च कार्याकार्ये भयाभये ।
> बन्धं **मोक्षं** च या वेत्ति बुद्धि: सा पार्थ सात्त्विकी ॥ ३० ॥
>
> 18.30 The intellect which knows the path of work and renunciation, what ought to be done and what ought not to be done, fear and
> fearlessness, bondage and **liberation** that intellect is Sattvic
> (pure), O Arjun
>
> ---
>
> [BG. 18.66](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=66&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1)
>  सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज । अहं त्वां
> सर्वपापेभ्यो **मोक्षयिष्यामि** मा श‍ुच: ॥ ६६ ॥
>
> > 18.66 Abandoning all duties, take refuge in Me alone: **I will liberate thee** from all sins; grieve not.
>
> *All the English Translations by [Swami Sivananda](https://www.dlshq.org/download/bhagavad-gita/) (Divine Life Society)*.

---

### Conclusion:

- So, we can see that although the exact verbatim is not found in the Gītā, however, the implication is clear on  Mokṣa as the Supreme Goal of Human life.
- ###### Specifically, the verses BG. 5.28 & 6.14-15 underlines such an idea quite strongly.
- The idea of "Liberation" may also be found in [BG. 2.51](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=51&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1), [BG 5.2](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=2&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1), [BG 5.17](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=17&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1), [BG. 7.14](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=7&field_nsutra_value=14&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1), [BG 7.29](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=7&field_nsutra_value=29&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1), [BG 16.5](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=16&field_nsutra_value=5&htrskd=1&hcchi=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1), etc.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer, May God bless you forever

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer!  @Yogie  May God Bless everyone! :))

Answer (score 3):

Krishna tells Arjuna that people go to the abode of the gods that they think of.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06034.htm

> Whichever form (of godhead) one remembereth when one casteth off, at the end, (his) body, unto that one he goeth, O son of Kunti, having habitually meditated on it always. Therefore, think of me at all times, and engage in battle. Fixing thy mind and understanding on me, thou wilt, without doubt, come even to me. Thinking (of the Supreme) with a mind not running to other objects and endued with abstraction in the form of uninterrupted application, one goeth, O son of Pritha, unto the Divine and Supreme male Being.

> He who always thinketh of me with mind ever withdrawn from all other objects, unto that devotee always engaged on meditation, I am, O Partha, easy of access. High-souled persons who have achieved the highest perfection, attaining to me, do not incur re-birth which is the abode of sorrow and which is transient, All the worlds, O Arjuna, from the abode of Brahman downwards have to go through a round of births, on attaining to me, however, O son of Kunti, there is no re-birth.

Krishna tells about his supreme seat.

> hey who know a day of Brahman to end after a thousand Yugas, and a night (of his) to terminate after a thousand Yugas are persons that know day and night. 3 On the advent of (Brahman's) day everything that is manifest springeth from the unmanifest; and when (his) night cometh, into that same which is called unmanifest all things disappear. That same assemblage of creatures, springing forth again and again, dissolveth on the advent of night, and springeth forth (again), O son of Pritha, when day cometh, constrained (by the force of action, etc.) 4. There is, however, another entity, unmanifest and eternal, which is beyond that unmanifest, and which is not destroyed when all the entities are destroyed. It is said to be unmanifest and indestructible. They call it the highest goal, attaining which no one hath to come back. That is my Supreme seat

> "The Holy One said, 'Once more still, O mighty-armed one, listen to my supernal words which, from desire of (thy) good, I say unto thee that wouldst be pleased (therewith). 2 The hosts of gods know not my origin, nor the great Rishis, since I am, in every way, the source of the gods and the great Rishis. 3 He that knoweth me as the Supreme Lord of the worlds, without birth and beginning, (he), undeluded among mortals, is free from all sins. Intelligence, knowledge, the absence of delusion, forgiveness, truth, self-restraint, and tranquillity, pleasure, pain, birth, death, fear, and also security, abstention from harm, evenness of mind, contentment, ascetic austerities, gift, fame, infamy, these several attributes of creatures arise from me. The Seven great Rishis, the four Maharishis before (them), and the Manus, partaking of my nature, were born from my mind, of whom in this world are these offsprings.

---

Supreme seat of Krishna.

> Those that are free from pride and delusion, that have subdued the evil of attachment, that are steady in the contemplation of the relation of the Supreme to the individual self, from whom desire hath departed, freed from the pairs of opposites known by the names of pleasure and pain (and the like), repair, undeluded, to that eternal seat.

Answer (score 3):

Throughout Bhagavad Geeta Krishna Paramatma dictates duties, prescribes different paths but never the purpose.
But if you insist, we can get it in multiple shlokas spread across the text and then connect the dots.

In fact he leaves it to Arjuna, thereby the reader, to contemplate on the satwika, rajasa and tamasa ways and choose his purpose/goal (18.63). (Note: Dwaita philosophy interprets that the souls themselves are characterized in such a way that the individual chooses his/her destiny accordingly)

> इति ते ज्ञानमाख्यातं गुह्याद्गुह्यतरं मया ।
> विमृश्यैतदशेषेण **यथेच्छसि तथा कुरु** ॥ १८ - ६३॥

So I will presume that you are talking about the purpose of a satwik soul. **Krishna Paramatma mentions this as "jneya" and "jnanagamya" - the objective of the highest knowledge**. That is nothing but Himself (13.18)

> ज्योतिषामपि तज्ज्योतिस्तमसः परमुच्यते ।
> ज्ञानं ज्ञेयं **ज्ञानगम्यं** हृदि सर्वस्य विष्ठितम्॥ १३ - १८॥

and then he commands Arjuna to leave everything and take shelter of only Him (18.66)

> सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य **मामेकं शरणं व्रज** ।
> अहं त्वा सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः ॥ १८ - ६६॥

As for the rebirth he mentions ignorance and non-cognizance of His supremacy as the cause (9.24); and that is also the reason for "moha" or attachment

> अहं हि सर्वयज्ञानां भोक्ता च प्रभुरेव च ।
> न तु मामभिजानन्ति तत्त्वेनात**श्च्यवन्ति** ते ॥ ९ - २४॥

> नादत्ते कस्यचित्पापं न चैव सुकृतं विभुः ।
> **अज्ञानेनावृतं** ज्ञानं तेन **मुह्यन्ति** जन्तवः ॥ ५ - १५॥

He mentions misdeeds or "paapa" blocks an individual from truly surrendering to Him (7.28)

> येषां त्वन्तगतं पापं जनानां पुण्यकर्मणाम्।
> ते द्वन्द्वमोहनिर्मुक्ता भजन्ते मां दृढव्रताः ॥ ७ - २८॥

So what is the reason for this "paapa"? This is answered in 3.37; that it is the rajas which generates unhealthy desires and hatred

> काम एष क्रोध एष रजोगुणसमुद्भवः ।
> महाशनो महापाप्मा विद्ध्येनमिह वैरिणम्॥ ३ - ३७॥

Speaking of attachment, greed, etc. he mentions in 16.20 that those who does not cling on to God will indulge in them. Then not only will they rotate in various rebirths but eventually attain the most tragic climax. But I couldn't find any shloka directly relating attachment and greed to rebirth

> आसुरीं योनिमापन्ना मूढा जन्मनि जन्मनि ।
> मामप्राप्यैव कौन्तेय ततो यान्त्यधमां गतिम्॥ १६ - २०॥